# Perl- File handling without using regular expression

Tags: perl

I have a certain piece of script.

```
if (@ARGV != 2) {

    print "Please pass atleast one paramer\n";
    print "Usage:\n\t $0 <file_name><Pattern>\n";
    exit;
}
$File_name     = $ARGV[0];
$res_File_name = $File_name . "\.result\.txt";
$Pattern       = $ARGV[1]; chomp($Pattern);
open(FD,"$File_name") or die ("File '$File_name' could not be open \n");
open(WFD,">$res_File_name") or die("File $res_File_name could not be opened\n");

print "Enter begin match pattern: ";
$bgn = <stdin>; 
chomp($bgn);

print "Enter end match pattern: ";
$en = <stdin>; 
chomp($en);



while ($line = <FD>) {

    chomp($line);
    if ($line =~ /^$bgn/) { #seaching a patter at begining of the string.

        print "Begin pattern '$bgn' matched with the line '$line'\n";
    }
    if ($line =~ /$en$/) { #seaching a patter at end of the string.

        print "End pattern '$en' matched with the line '$line'\n";

      exit;
    }
print WFD $_ if(/$Pattern/);

}

close(FD);
close(WFD);
```

Here i need to do the following action
    -- In the begin pattern io enter some thing what is wriiten in my text file
    -- In the end pattern i write something ,Overall i am getting output

```
-- What is my aim is to copy those in some result.txt. How i can achieve it.
```

Please help me in this regards

Comment: What you actully need? Post the example output

Comment: Perl Search_Pattern.pl sample.txt for ex: the txt file contain some char like hello world, a beautiful and lovely climate. Now my search pattern use like this: Enter beging Pattern: h and Enter end pattern :e, so it searches the whole characters and return hello world, a beautiful and lovely climate. This works fine, but i need to copy the same to result.txt which is not working

Comment: Please, post a sample input file and expected result.

Comment: In order to  meaningful answer, we need some idea of what you're trying to do with input/output.

Comment: @Sobrique: See i have a long text file with logs written on it. I need only a particular statement from that log to be extracted. For instnce my log file has error written, i will do a search pattern find begining and end pattern and my complete statement which match those case will be extracted, and will be pasted in another text file result.txt

Comment: .... by which I mean  a sample of your source data and expected output.

Comment: Sobrique: I got the expected output

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
open(nis,"test.txt");
@ar = <nis>;
open(new,">result.txt");
print "Enter the first string : ";
chomp($fis = <>);
print "Enter the second string: ";
chomp($sec = <>);
@vr = map{m/^$fis.*$sec$/g} @ar;
print @vr,"\n";
```

Comment: I need it in windows cmd prompt